# How to visualize separate categories that share common features with radar charts?

Tags: clustering, data-visualization

I am working on a scientific research project with a real data-sample where I have applied EM clustering algorithm based on 5 criteria (e.g. Var1, Var 2, Var3, Var4, Var5)and I finally got 5 clusters that hold the following information:

Cluster 1:
1<=Var1<=2.333,
4.23<=Var2<=4.87,
3.6<=Var3<=4.5,
1.6<=Var4<=3.5,
3.9<=Var5<=4.8

Cluster 2:
2.1<=Var1<=3.5,
2.5<=Var2<=3.8,
2.8<=Var3<=4.6,
3.3<=Var4<=4.2,
2.2<=Var5<=4

and so on.. Can I visualize this information with radar chart in excel? If yes, how? Could you suggest me any other techniques?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your quesiton to add [these details](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [parallel coordinates plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates) is generally better than a radar chart for this purpose. Here's a parallel coordinates plot on a famous data set of 3 categories sharing 4 common features:

[image]

Each feature is a vertical axis instead of a radial axis like in a radar chart. The parallel axes make for better comparisons, and don't have the problem of tiny lines near the center.

I'm not an Excel user, but for making any kind of advanced chart in Excel, I know a couple great resources are:

- [Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/)
- [Jorge Camoes](http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/)